Problems making a card clickable and showing/hiding text
Could anyone help me out?
I want to click a card on this streamlit page and let that hide/unhide some text. Right now I can click the card, but nothing happens. Just below the card a I can click a hidden button and then the text appears. I would like to have the card be the button if that makes sense. I just cant figure out how to.
Cheers!
import streamlit as st
import json
from collections import defaultdict

# Load the JSON data
with open('trading_mistakes.json', 'r') as file:
data = json.load(file)

# Group mistakes by category
mistakes_by_category = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data.items():
    mistakes_by_category[value['category']].append({
        'id': key,
        'title': value['title'], 
        'description': value['description']
    })

# Set page config
st.set_page_config(layout="wide", page_title="Trading Mistakes")

# Define color gradients for each category
category_colors = {
    "Choose your Battles": ("#FF6B6B", "#FF8E8E"),
    "Entries": ("#4ECDC4", "#45B7AA"),
    "Stops": ("#FFA07A", "#FF8C61"),
    "Exits": ("#82C0CC", "#6AAEBB"),
    "Targets": ("#F9C74F", "#F4B63C"),
    "Tijdens de trade & executie": ("#9B5DE5", "#8A4FD3"),
    "Moneymanagement": ("#00B4D8", "#0096B7"),
    "Aandeel en markt zaken die je op het verkeerde been kunnen zetten": ("#FF9F1C", 
"#FF8C00"),
    "Denkfouten & mentale staat": ("#8AC926", "#7AB321"),
    "Rules & Ethics": ("#FF99C8", "#FF80B3")
}

# Custom CSS
st.markdown("""
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
   family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.stApp {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.card-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.card-title {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-description {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.category {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.stButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.stButton > button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: transparent !important;
}

.stButton > button:hover {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.stButton > button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.stButton > button > div {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
""", unsafe_allow_html=True)

# App title
st.title("Trading Mistakes")

# Initialize session state for card visibility
if 'active_card' not in st.session_state:
     st.session_state.active_card = None

# Display mistakes by category
for category, mistakes in mistakes_by_category.items():
    st.markdown(f"<h2 class='category'>{category}</h2>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
 
    # Calculate the number of columns based on the screen width
    num_columns = 5  # You can adjust this number to fit more or fewer cards per row

    # Create rows of cards
    for i in range(0, len(mistakes), num_columns):
        cols = st.columns(num_columns)
        for j in range(num_columns):
            if i + j < len(mistakes):
                mistake = mistakes[i + j]
                card_id = f"card_{mistake['id']}"
            
                with cols[j]:
                    # Create a container for the card and button
                    st.markdown(f"""
                    <div class='card-container'>
                        <div class='card' style='background: linear-gradient(135deg, 
    {category_colors[category][0]}, {category_colors[category][1]});'>
                            <h3 class='card-title'>{mistake['title']}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)                    
                    # Button to toggle description visibility (hidden under the card)
                    if st.button("", key=f"btn_{card_id}"):
                        if st.session_state.active_card == card_id:
                            st.session_state.active_card = None
                        else:
                            st.session_state.active_card = card_id
                
                # Show description if the card is active
                if st.session_state.active_card == card_id:
                    st.markdown(f"<div class='card-description'> 
   {mistake['description']}</div>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
            else:
                with cols[j]:
                    st.empty()

# Debug information 
st.sidebar.write("Debug Information")
st.sidebar.write(f"Active Card: {st.session_state.active_card}")

The JSON looks like this:
{
"1.1": {
  "title": "dummy dummy",
  "category": "dummy dummy",
  "description": "dummy dummy"
},
"1.2": {
  "title": "dummy dummy",
  "category": "Choose your Battles",
  "description": "dummy dummy"
},

